# Redirection to a web page not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I am trying to redirect when someone clicks on my hyperlink. 
The address of the page appears in the address bar but it does not load. Address is placed in a tag `{{tag}}`. Tag is set value using `href`.

Comment: Will you please share your code ?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried.

Comment: I guess, maybe you don't place corresponding id

Comment: The issue is resolved , thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Will Successfully Redirect as there is no **# hash** in url

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function () {
     $location.url('/controller2?dataId='+33);
}
```

> This Will not Redirect Due To **# hash** in Url
>
> So Add  **$location.reload();**
>
> It Will Change Url + navigate your page

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function () {
     $location.url('#/controller2?dataId='+33);
     $location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in angularJs

```
window.location.href = '/Controller/Action';
```